# Testing helper in rspec with I18n lazy lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, internationalization, rails-i18n

Consider this example. I have a Product model which has `discount_percentage`. And we're maintaining multiple locales. In the view we do not want the i18n stuff mess up the view. So we make a helper to read better and probably reuse it in other views: `render_product_discount` (code please see below) which will render the discount status of this product. And we use i18n lazy lookup feature throughout the application. But when we want to test this helper method we get a Error:

```
# RuntimeError:
# Cannot use t(".product_discount") shortcut because path is not available
```

because there is no `path` available for translation helper to expand the lazy translation key.

Expected Output: This product has 20% discount.

Helper name: `render_product_discount`

```
def render_product_discount
  t('.product_discount', discount_percentage: product.discount_percentage)
end

# es.yml
es:
  products:
    show:
      product_discount: Este producto tiene un %{discount_percentage} descuento.

# en.yml
en:
  products:
    show:
      product_discount: This product has %{discount_percentage} discount.
```

How to workaround this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you stub t as:

```
helper.stub(:t).with('.product_discount', discount_percentage: product.discount_percentage) { "This product has #{product.discount_percentage}% discount." }
```

you can test with:

```
expect(helper.render_product_discount).to eq("This product has #{product.discount_percentage}% discount.")
```

**Edit**
As SebastianG answered, you can set `@virtual_path` with the expected path to use like in the main code, what I think it´s a better approach when possible.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes you can set the needed virtual path, so that translate knows how to use shortcuts.

**In Helper Specs**

```
before { helper.instance_variable_set(:@virtual_path, "admin.path.form") }
```

Now `t('.word')` looks for `admin.path.form.word`.

Comment: Does this still work in Rails 4.2? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet with 4.2, sorry.

Comment: I think my problem is a bit different, please take a look at this post I created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229368/rspec-rails-stub-virtual-path-for-translation-helper-to-test-an-application

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clue how to fix your problem. However, latest Rails still uses the virtual_path instance variable: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/787892905ee2268854f3a247c6b3b4e9dbadb6cc/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L95

Comment: I know, I added a breakpoint there so I found out that the `@virtual_path` is not set. Thanks anyway.