# RSpec & Rails: Stub @virtual_path for translation helper to test an application helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-i18n

I have a helper `page_title_default` in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def page_title_default(options = {})
  t '.title', options
end
```

Now I want to test it like this:

```
describe '#page_title' do
  subject { page_title }

  it { ... }
end
```

end

This results in the following error:

```
Cannot use t(".title") shortcut because path is not available
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774156/testing-helper-in-rspec-with-i18n-lazy-lookup) it should be possible to stub the `@virtual_path` variable like this:

```
helper.instance_variable_set(:@virtual_path, "admin.path.form")
```

But this doesn't seem to help: While I am able to stub it and then to call something like `helper.t '.something'` directly in the test, it doesn't work for the translation helper which is used in the `page_title_default` method (which still has `@virtual_path` set to `nil`). So it seems it's not the same instance of translation helper. But how can I find the `page_title_default` method one's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
RSpec.describe PageHelper, :type => :helper do
  describe "#page_title_default" do
    before do
      allow(helper).to receive(:t).with(".title", {}) { "Hello!" }
    end

    subject { helper.page_title_default }

    it { is_expected.to eq "Hello!" }
  end
end
```

We're stubbing the "translated" string returned here to decouple the spec of `helper` from "real" translations, which may appear to be fragile for the test of `PageHelper` itself - the tests would fail every time you change the translations of ".title".

On the other hand - if you change the key used, eg. from ".title" to ".default_title" it should fail, because it is change of behaviour.

I think the proper text displayed should be tested on different level of test (integration tests, to be specific). Please, check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415158/add-i18n-translations-to-rspec-tests/10671020#10671020).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works, nice! But why do I need to call explicit `subject { helper.xxx }`? When only having `subject { xxx }`, it doesn't work. What's the implicit receiver in the 2nd code? Why isn't it the same as the explicit one?

Comment: Hey! This is interesting question! This is because the method would be called in context of your test (internally, they are classes), so call like this would end up with error similar to `undefined local variable or method 'page_title_default'` - which is true, because this method is not implemented in your test. You could use it this way, if you defined that method within `describe` block - `def page_title_default; helper.page_title_default end`. Please check my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368762/implicit-using-subject-in-rspec-example-doesnt-work/29368953#29368953).